# Component Architecture: Return type Subclass of Superclass Ideal Solutions

Tags: java, objective-c, class, types, libgdx

I'm pretty new to java in general so I've been following a plethora of tutorials. so FEEL FREE TO CORRECT ME AT EVERY TURN! (yes even in code inefficiencies as well!!)

I currently have the issue of getting a single method to return different subclasses/types from a superclass.

The ***problem code is at the bottom of the post.***

Get ready because I'm going to throw this at you.

I've run into a **Java language barrier**.

I'm in the process of following a [tutorial(libGDX)](http://www.kilobolt.com/introduction.html) to use **LibGDX** and another tutorial to implement component based design (see link just below)

**I've never seen Objective-C code until now so these are my feeble attempts to convert the [tutorial code(component design)](https://www.raywenderlich.com/24878/introduction-to-component-based-architecture-in-games) to java**

Currently the idea is to have an `Entity` that will use various `Component`s to access different functional abilities(health, rendering, movement, etc) inside the game.

I'm attempting to get the `Component` associated with an `Entity` and check its fields, but I've run into some sort of issue with returning class types.

## Component System

***Component.java***

```
public class Component {

}
```

***HealthComponent.java***

```
public class HealthComponent extends Component{
    public boolean alive;
}
```

***RenderComponent.java***

```
public class RenderComponent extends Component {
    public boolean canRender;
}
```

## Entity System

I store `Entity`s with their `Component`s each within a list(ArrayMap[LibGDX]) of available active `Component`s so that I can get all `Entity`s using a specified `Component`. Or in this case, get a specific `Component` associated with an `Entity`

**Entity.java**

```
public class Entity {
    private int eid;

    public Entity (int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public int eid () {
        return this.eid;
    }
}
```

**EntityManager.java**

```
public class EntityManager {
    public ArrayMap<String, ArrayMap<Integer, Component>> componentsByClass;
    // Some other stuff like constructors and methods
    public Component getComponentOfClassForEntity(Component component, Entity entity) {
        //returns Component type
        return componentsByClass.get(component.getClass().getSimpleName()).get(entity.eid());
    }
}
```

### My problem comes to this part

My understanding is in order to stay as DRY as possible I don't want to have multiple different methods for each `Component` subclass just to return a different class type for the `ExampleComponent`. It would be very convenient if I could get this working smoothly with some sort of type/class smoother outer awesome thingy without any crazy hacks that are bad practices. Also, I'm assuming some if/then statements could work but it seems like there is a better way what with my limited knowledge and all.

I attempt to :

```
Component health = this.entityManager.getComponentOfClassForEntity(healthComponent, entity);
// No errors, however I don't really have a health component now do I?...Trying out:
if((HealthComponent)health.alive) // Cannot resolve symbol "alive"...
```

or the same but change the type:

```
HealthComponent health = this.entityManager.getComponentOfClassForEntity(healthComponent, entity);
// Required: HealthComponent
// Found: Component
// Sucks as I'd like to be able able to follow the DRY conventionthingy:
RenderComponent render = this.entityManager.getComponentOfClassForEntity(renderComponent, entity);
if(render.canRender))//plsssrenddrr
etc...
```

In full, I understand that you're not supposed to be able to do that, but my question is what is an ideal solution that doesn't break convention or make for a hacky and poorly coded game.

**Perhaps there's a better Component based Architecture out there that is a cleaner and more do-able solution...**

Thanks so much!!

Comment: `if( ( (HealthComponent) health) .alive)` This should resolve. But is there any reason why Ashley does not work for you?

Comment: ah, what is the difference between `((HealthComponent) health)` and  `(HealthComponent)health`? Let me try it out...

Comment: None in that context. But `(HealthComponent)health.alive` let's you cast `health.alive` value into `HealthComponent` which is not desirable. You want to cast `health` into the `Healthcomponent` and then call a function on it.

Comment: My main goal starting this game project was to learn how to think and develop in component style architecture while learning how to program in general. Exercising 2 skills at once...

I'm sure Ashley works great! I'll definitely consider dropping everything and moving over to it.

However, I'm definitely hoping to learn the ins and outs of the core java language before working with too many frameworks...

Comment: Oh wow... that didn't even cross my mind. casting a value as the class? yikes...

Comment: `if( ( (HealthComponent) health) .alive)` resolves. Is this a good conventional solution? I've read that runtime errors can occur when casting...

Comment: Yeah if you cast something that cannot be casted you run into issues. You can always do a check for it `if (health instanceOf HealthCompnent.class && ( (HealthComponent) health) .alive)` would do the trick in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a conventional solution, I am no expert programmer and I have poor knowledge of ECS systems other then some ashley and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take the DRY principle to its logical conclusion and **Don't Repeat Someone Else** (if someone can turn that into a snazzy acronym, then let me know).

There are some good ECS libraries for Java already out there, and I highly recommend that you try to use (or extend) one of those instead of creating your own. Quite frankly, if you try to build an ECS of your own, you're probably never going to finish the game itself.

Out of the many ECS available, I'm going to recommend you start with [Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki) or [Artemis](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/wiki).

Ashley is a light-weight ECS that appears to be affiliated with the libGDX group in some way- the libGDX setup tool gives you the option to include Ashley in the gradle files it generates for you. In my humble opinion, it has more boilerplate code than I'd like, but that also means it's doing less black magic (i.e. reflection).

I personally moved to Artemis because of the syntax benefits, and it appears to be further optimized and more actively maintained. If you want to add it to your game, you can follow [the instructions here](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/wiki/GettingStarted).

All that being said, these are both great libraries which deserve a more in-depth comparison, and so long as you use one of these (or another ECS library) it should allow you to accomplish your goal.

Now if you're more interested in making the ECS than the game (and I've totally been there), I would still recommend you look at the approaches these two libraries took (their code is on GitHub) and see how they dealt with the syntax issue.

Comment: Interesting stuff!! I don't fully understand what you're trying to get at. Did you take a look at what I was trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Descrubb he is trying to tell you that you should not be building a Entity Component System if you want to create a game. A proper and efficient Entity Component System is a huge project on it's own and there is no need to reinvent the wheel. So unless you really want to study ECS it's worth to work on.

Comment: Oh, I understand...

True, I'm not really looking to building the system all at once but to implement a portion of the design at a time as needed. It's not even close to what exists out there if you consider what I have so far. But its a start... and If I continue down this path I'll have my own system built and the knowledge and experience with dos and don'ts.

I was hoping to acquire a specific answer that could explain whether it is possible or impossible and perhaps explain why. And then, perhaps from there, a lead to a solution that could work through alternative methods...

Thanks!

Comment: No @Descrubb, I do not believe you understand. By the time you have gained the knowledge you realize your system is worth shit and you should start over. Then you learn some more and realize it's not much better then shit and you start over again. So like I said "unless you really want to learn about creating ECS, stop making them and leave it to the pro's". There is no harm or shame in using those awesome tools already out there, in fact I think one should shame himself for creating some half arsed wheel himself rather then using a competent wheel of someone else.

Comment: @Madmenyo you're totally right. Whatever system I make won't be worth very much at all. Somehow, I believe that attempting to make a system will help get experience with the nitty gritties that you may not run into using a framework. That's hireable quality stuff... imagine resume status "Java Guru". Ofc there's the other side where a framework will speed up everything by a hundredfold, but if I have the nitty gritty experience then I might even be able to extend the framework myself...

Comment: Then yes @Descrubb, if you want to be hired as a ECS expert for a company that want to build it's own ECS engine those skills are good but I guess these position require a CS degree as well. If you want to make a game then use the tools available. If you want to be a carpenter you don't need to make your own hammers and nails right? There is no harm in creating an ECS system for knowledge, but using one of the proven ones out there grand you knowledge as well and you can extend on these too.

Comment: @Descrubb The reason I answered the way I did was because I used to think as you do, but I found my projects kept turning into half-baked ECS instead of games. I would propose another way of looking at it: If you focus on using ECS, you will learn what is needed from an ECS, and that will let you look at the existing ECS and say, " You know, this ECS is missing ____. I should fix that." Then you'll fork their repo, make your addition, and send them a pull request. You will gain the knowledge you seek, and create code that others are more likely to use.